# Wildfly throws UnsupportedOperationException (Naming context is read-only) on start

Tags: spring, ubuntu, jboss, wildfly

We're setting up a new staging server (running Ubuntu), and are encountering errors when starting WildFly. The main one seens to be

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: WFLYNAM0043: Naming context is read-only
```

which then causes many errors about missing dependencies.

We have set up our (liquibase) database on another server, which we can ssh into internally. We've scoured StackOverflow as well, and attempted to add

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.lookupExtensionInBeanManager=**true**"
```

to our standalone.conf, standalone.bat, and standalone.conf.bat (for the sake of having tried everything!). We also saw that this should've been fixed in WildFly 7.1.1, we're running 9 ourselves (to emulate the live server). 
We tried manually installing the dependencies but there are so many - and honestly we think that's just not the main issue.

We're also running nginx and Redis, we saw in the server.log (see below) that the error happens after "Started Hibernate Redis cache" but the error itself seems to be specific to WildFly.

A chunk of server.log is below:

```
2019-04-03 10:52:38,252 INFO  [com.company.ejb.util.config.ConfigRetriever] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) Successfully found and read the config file at /opt/wildfly/config.yml
2019-04-03 10:52:38,300 INFO  [com.company.ejb.entity.cache.RedisRegionFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) Started Hibernate Redis cache
2019-04-03 10:52:46,896 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Event] (MSC service thread 1-2) WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2019-04-03 10:52:47,041 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."DoThePublish.ear".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."DoThePublish.ear".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: WFLYNAM0043: Naming context is read-only
        at org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.requireOwner(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:161)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.createSubcontext(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:151)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.createSubcontext(NamingContext.java:417)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.createSubcontext(InitialContext.java:298)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.createSubcontext(NamingContext.java:425)
        [...]

2019-04-03 10:52:47,078 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "DoThePublish.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"DoThePublish. ear\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"DoThePublish.ear\".WeldStartService: Failed to
 start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: WFLYNAM0043: Naming context is read-only
        at org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.requireOwner(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:161)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.createSubcontext(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:151)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.createSubcontext(NamingContext.java:417)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.createSubcontext(InitialContext.java:298)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.createSubcontext(NamingContext.java:425)
        [...]
"}}
2019-04-03 10:52:47,178 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "DoThePublish.ear" (runtime-name : "DoThePublish.ear")
2019-04-03 10:52:47,186 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report 
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."DoThePublish.ear".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."DoThePublish.ear".WeldStartService: Failed to start service

2019-04-03 10:52:47,581 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
2019-04-03 10:52:47,582 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
2019-04-03 10:52:47,582 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 9.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.1.Final) started (with errors) in 42472ms - Started 4599 of 5108 services (362 services failed or missing dependencies, 209 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Then following that there's a bunch of missing dependencies (there's looaaaads of these):

```
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."DoThePublish.ear"."CoreEjb.jar".component.AbstractEntityMainSB.CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."DoThePublish.ear"."CoreEjb.jar".component.AbstractEntityMainSB.START]
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."DoThePublish.ear"."CoreEjb.jar".component.AbstractEntityMainSB.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."DoThePublish.ear"."CoreEjb.jar".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart, service jboss.deployment.subunit."DoThePublish.ear"."CoreEjb.jar".deploymentCompleteService]
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."DoThePublish.ear"."CoreEjb.jar".component.AbstractEntityMainSB.VIEW."com.company.ejb.session.AbstractEntityMainSBL".LOCAL (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."DoThePublish.ear"."CoreEjb.jar".component.AbstractEntityMainSB.START]
```

We've tried comparing the setup to the existing production (live) server, but there has been a big turnaround in the dev team so no-one knows exactly how they're set up. There are no setup instructions so we're trying things as we go along - perhaps the previous server encountered these same issues but we've no idea.

We are wanting to fix this exception to hopefully be able to start wildfly (and thus our website) without issues (or at least move on to the next error...) Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is something missing in log you provided, there should be also something about what code/bean in your application triggered this exception.

Comment: Thanks ctomc, I'll keep that in mind next time I post a chunk of log. I had to shorten it because the question was too long and it wouldn't let me post it otherwise! We managed to figure it out, I've written down an answer and will accept it tomorrow (when it lets me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bunch of trying, we figured it out. The line we tried to implement needed to be changed a bit:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.lookupExtensionInBeanManager=true"
```

So we removed the 'set' and removed the asterisks and stuff. In our case it was the .conf file that needed the line, I believe for different types of implementations it might be the .bat or .conf.bat - sorry I can't help further with that.

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I recently got this same error on startup of JBOSS EAP 7.2 and Wildfly 12. In my case, it's an old Hibernate Java application. The mapping of entities in the `hibernate.cfg.xml`. My problem was that someone put the name attribute in the `<session-factory name="">`, and that particular application goes up two contexts! On the startup of the second context, I get the error:

> `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: WFLYNAM0043: Naming context is read-only`

Removing the name from the session-factory solved the problem.